# The type or namespace name 'builtInShaderGraphSaveContext' could not be found unity problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Can anyone help me , I was learning from https://youtu.be/FbM4CkqtOuA?t=126 this codemonkey youtube channel . The extension is here : https://unitycodemonkey.com/download.php?dt=videoProjectFiles&yid=FbM4CkqtOuA .

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPei.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the script that reports the error to the Editor folder. The location of this folder is very arbitrary, and it can be placed under the initial directory of the Asset. Of course other English should also work. If there is no Editor folder, just create a new Editor folder.